# Get content in href page when crawl data in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-crawler, nokogiri

I want to crawl data from a website. In this website :

HTML :

```
<div>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="http://.../place1">Place1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://.../place2">Place2</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Inside "http://.../place1":

```
<div>
 <p>Place 1</p>
 <img src="...">
<div>
```

How can I crawl data inside href using 'Nokogiri" gem? (Data in other page when we click )

When I research, I only find the way to crawl data in a page. Not find how to crawl data inside href page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to crawl data inside href, you **have to** create a new request to crawl data inside it.

```
...
# require 'open-uri'
href = 'http://.../place1'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(href))
...
```

Comment: Thanks you so much :))

Answer (score 0):

You can get all links by `.css` method. Then you can crawl by like this

```
# require 'open-uri'
links = doc.css('a').map { |link| link['href'] }
links.each do |link|
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(link))
end
```